# How to set active class and fetch data form database on tab based nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here I have a tab-based nav-bar [image] and I want to the active class functionality when someone clicks on the tab.

EX- Let us click the second tab, it should be active and fetch the data from URL on click.

Here the problem is in my code is - when I am clicking on the second tab the class is showing active but the content is not displaying.

Could you guys suggest any solution to render data dynamically from the database and set the active class to that tab when I click on that?

```
 <div class="box-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active" ><a href="/delhi/list_sudents">Delhi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mumbai/list_sudents">Mumbai</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li a').click(function(e) {

        $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
/script>
```

Comment: I think u r trying to retrieve data from db when the particular tab is active I'm right?

Comment: Please share full html code

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/qrn0sdfv/2/). You can use data attributes like in this fiddle.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li').click(function(e) {
       var $_this = $(this)
       $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $_this.addClass("active");
            var url = $_this.attr("data-url");
            var data = {} //your post data
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "some.php",
                data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                // Do somthing with your data
            });
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" data-url="/delhi/list_sudents">Mumbai</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" data-url="/delhi/list_sudents">Delhi</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Not working redirecting to the URLs in my case and I want the same layout as attached in the image. But it's changing the layout.

Comment: I didn't get you... actually on click I want the class active and it should call the Django view to render the corresponding templates dynamically.